# Play audio from app, even when it is in the background

Tags: xcode, audio, background

I am having difficulties determining how I would play audio in the background for my iOS app. I have a NSTimer and wish to have a sound be played when it reaches 5 minutes, even when in the background. I already have the audio background mode enabled, but unsure how to accomplish my idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under capabilities select the following:

[image]

In your plist make sure where it says "Application does not run in background" is NO.

[image]

Then add the following to your your appDelegate.m file.

```
  NSError *sessionError = nil;
NSError *activationError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&sessionError];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];
```

In the following method:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Where would I add in the sound that I want? Also, I want to keep an NSTimer going in the background so that that app knows when to play the sound. I already have the timer set up and working.

Comment: add it anywhere you'd like in your viewcontroller implementation file. If you follow the instruction above your NSSTimer will run in the background.

Comment: Official Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1668/_index.html