# Play audio in background (play when using other APP)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I created an app for streaming audio (and send mail as well) but I have a problem, my app will not keep playing after I press the home button.

I use XCODE 6.4 and the mediaplayer.framework to play the stream it is in viewcontroller and I have been activating the background mode Audio & airplay.

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong here, I really want to learn it.

code:

```
NSURL *videoStreamURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://streamlink.m3u"];


_player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoStreamURL];
_player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 530, self.view.frame.size.width, 38);
[self.view addSubview:_player.view];

[_player play];
```

Comment: @RosdiKasim how to i post the code, it will not let me paste it in because of too many characters

Comment: Post the relevant part, not the entire program. Maybe the function where you play the audio.

Comment: NSURL *videoStreamURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mystreamhere.m3u"];
    
    
    _player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoStreamURL];
    _player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 530, self.view.frame.size.width, 38);
    [self.view addSubview:_player.view];
    
    [_player play];

Comment: Hi, I mean edit your question and add the code there. Not in the comment section. 

Comment: its in the question now @RosdiKasim

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180914/play-audio-from-app-even-when-it-is-in-the-background

Comment: yes i just tested it, thank you, but it still kill the music as son as i push the home button